# Can I reuse Range<String.Index> between different Strings or should I use NSRange?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I encountered the problem where getting a substring from two identical strings returns different values.
It only happens in specific situation in my app and I couldn't replicate it in a sample code so I'll just share my findings from the debugger console.

```swift
// `range` is a NSRange
(lldb) po range
▿ {212, 1}
  - location : 212
  - length : 1

// Here I'm comparing two strings that I'm using. As you can see, they're identical.
(lldb) po parent.text == textView.string
true

// You can see that if I convert String to NSString an get a substring using NSRange, returned values are the same. That's correct.
(lldb) po (textView.string as NSString).substring(with: range)
"O"

(lldb) po (parent.text as NSString).substring(with: range)
"O"

// Let's convert NSRange to Range<String.Index> and use it to extract a substring.
// Returned value is correct on this string.
(lldb) po textView.string[Range<String.Index>(range, in: textView.string)!]
"O"

// But if we try to reuse the same Range<String.Index> on a second string, returned substring is wrong. Why? 
(lldb) po parent.text[Range<String.Index>(range, in: textView.string)!]
" "
```

Comment: Hi, assuming `textView` and `parent` are `UITextView` instances, is `textView.string` referring to a property of your own `UITextView` subclass? Because UIKit's `UITextView` does not have a `.string` property.

Comment: @Thisura, `textView` is a NSTextView on macOS but I assume this would work similar on iOS (?). `parent.Text` is a `@Binding` on one of my SwiftUI views.